# Como dar formato de numero de teléfono en PHP

Tags: php

Tengo una variable llamada `$telephone` y esta contiende un numero telefónico de Republica Dominicana, ejemplo: *8098872070*

Mi objetivo es convertir ese mismo número en *(809) 887-2070*
Este es el tipo de formato que quiero darle a el numero de teléfono que tengo almacenado en mi variable `$telephone`

Espero su ayuda, un saludo

Comment: Trátalo como un string y añade los caracteres que te interesen. Por cierto, aquí las preguntas de "Quiero hacer esto, hacedlo por mí" no suelen ser bien recibidas. Si has intentado algo y tienes un error expón ambas cosas, si no has intentado nada, primero inténtalo.

Comment: @Benito-B Ese es el problema, es que no se como hacerlo y buscado mucho en Google pero no me aparece nada

Comment: Pues busca en la documentación de php, por ejemplo lo más fácil: [substring](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.substr.php) con ese método puedes coger "trozos" de un string, no tendrás más que concatenar los trozos con lo que tú quieres y ya está. Así es como se aprende, no copiando y pegando código que hagan otros por tí. En la documentación de php tienes la explicación de cada método y además un montón de ejemplos diferentes, que podrás adaptar a tus necesidades... pero claro, no sirve con copiar y pegar, hay que esforzarse un poco!

Comment: Muchas gracias @Benito-B

Comment: Puede que esto te ayude a resolver lo que buscas https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4708248/formatting-phone-numbers-in-php

Comment: @EdgarGc Muchas gracias, lo he conseguido gracias a ti y a una respuesta que me ha servido

Answer (score 1, accepted):

He conseguido solucionar mi problema con un pequeño trozo de código que he encontrado aquí en este mismo foro.

```
<?php

$telephone = "8098877020"; 
$format = "(".substr($telephone,0,3).")"." ".substr($telephone,5,3)."-".substr($telephone,6,4);

echo $format;
```

Espero que este código logre hacer lo que ustedes buscan como me ha servido a mi